# Finding unknown values in Matrix with eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

"Consider the companion matrix  $$A =  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1\\
    a & b & c
    \end{pmatrix}$$Knowing that  −1 ,  3  and  −2  are the eigenvalues of $A$ , what is $a$, $b$ and $c$?

I have tried to find $c$ with the trace of the Matrix: $0+0+c = tr(A) = -1 + 3 -2 \Rightarrow c = 0$ (sum of eigenvalues), and find $a$ using the determinant of A and by multiplying eigenvalues $det(A) = -1 \times a = (-1) \times (3) \times (-2) = 6 \Rightarrow a = -6$. But like it is wrong according to solutions.

How can I find the values for $a, b, c$?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a $\mathbb v$ such that $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\a&b&c\end{bmatrix}\mathbb v = -\mathbb v$

$\begin{bmatrix} v_2\\v_3\\av_1+bv_2+cv_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -v_1\\-v_2\\-v_3\end{bmatrix}$

$\mathbb v = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $a-b+c = -1$

This together with what you know about $a = 6, c = 0$ would imply that if the matrix is diagonalizable $b$ must equal $7$

Answer (score 0):

Characteristic polynomial is $-x^3+cx^2+bx+a$

Knowing that eigenvalues are $-1,3,-2$ we must have

$-(x+1)(x-3)(x+2)=-x^3+7 x+6=0$

thus $a=6,b=7,c=0$

Comment: The eigenvalues are $1, 2,-3$ otherwise, this looks fine.

Comment: @DougM Thank you!